# jupyter notebook does not render LaTeX properly

Tags: python, rendering, jupyter-notebook, mathjax

I started using python with the jupyter notebook and I really like the markdown feature. The only problem (more esthetically) is that the printing is not like the standard LaTeX/Mathjax rendering.

This is my first cell

```
import sympy as sm
import numpy as np
```

This is my second cell (example code from [documentation](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Notebook/Display%20System.ipynb#LaTeX))

```
%%latex
\begin{align}
\nabla \times \vec{\mathbf{B}} -\, \frac1c\, \frac{\partial\vec{\mathbf{E}}}{\partial t} & = \frac{4\pi}{c}\vec{\mathbf{j}} \\
\nabla \cdot \vec{\mathbf{E}} & = 4 \pi \rho \\
\nabla \times \vec{\mathbf{E}}\, +\, \frac1c\, \frac{\partial\vec{\mathbf{B}}}{\partial t} & = \vec{\mathbf{0}} \\
\nabla \cdot \vec{\mathbf{B}} & = 0
\end{align}
```

The result in the notebook looks like in the following picture

[image]

Comparing this with standard Mathjax rendering

[image]

makes clear that the standard Mathjax looks more refined, hence more pleasant for the mathematical eye :D.

> **Question**: How, can I force my notebook rendering to be as in the
>   second picture?

Comment: My output looks like your first picture and it is using mathjax v2.6.0 with STIX-Web fonts. The example in the documentation is rendered using mathjax v2.7.1 and web TeX fonts. I think the main difference is in the font. I do not know how/if this can be changed but you can have a look at the [configuration options](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html#options) for the nb server.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution to printing markdown cells in a Jupyter Notebook. I have always had problems with this, and the built-in solutions do not always work.

What I do is upload the ipynb file to Colaboratory (https://colab.research.google.com/), a free service, and then print it.

Voila, problem solved.